# Emailing : no open rate available

Tags: civimail

I have a problem with one of my emailing campaign. The volume of tracked opening is equal to zero. But I see 203 clicks for this campaign, so I know the emailing was opened.
I checked the parameters, the tracking for opening was on.

What can generate this problem ? Do we have a possibility to retrive the data ?

Thanks a lot :)
Aude

Answer (score 2):

Note that for all the popular web email clients (gmail, ymail) and probably desktop clients too, image loading is disabled by default and the user explicitly has to enable image loading for an email address or globally.

At the best the open rate should be treated just as an approximation. The wikipedia article has a good summary of this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_rate

Comment: I'd be surprised that *every* contact has disabled displaying images (and now gmail by default pre-fetch the images, so last time I checked, it counted)

Comment: agreed. I just wanted to highlight that number of emails read != number of emails open. Also based on the characteristics of the group that it was sent to, the open rate could be radically high or low

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have a copy of the mailing in your mailbox as you received it? Could you view the html of the mailing to see if there is any img tag added? The way civimail works it to add a 1x1 transparent pixel, that is loaded from your civicrm website. Everytime someone loads that pixel, it means they are reading your mailing

If your mailing didn't have that image, that might be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

We were getting this problem as well.

The tracking image is embedded in the html of the emails sent by CiviCRM but opens are not being recorded. (it isn't an image blocking problem)

```
<img src="http://www.examplesite.org/sites/www.examplesite.org/modules/contrib/civicrm/extern/open.php?q=138122" width="1" height="1" alt="" border="0">
```

To test you can go directly to the url like this for your own site and see what happens and that will hopefully point you towards the solution.

It could be permissions on that folder/file or could be your firewall blocking the word "open" or "open.php" or your civicrm settings file may not be being found by the open.php script.  Or something else.

In our case it turns out that our firewall was blocking requests to "open.php?q="